# How can be request variables encoded by encodeURIComponent with ISO-8859-1 charset and not utf-8?

Tags: javascript

I working on website with ISO-8859-1 charset.
Request should be encoded partly by encodeURIComponent() , but this function encode with utf-8.

How can be request variables encoded by encodeURIComponent with ISO-8859-1 charset and not utf-8?(or other function that doing encoding with ISO-8859-1 or other way).

Update:
maybe use escape() js function poper option in this case?

Thanks,
Yosef

Comment: Where are you receiving the data? Any chance of converting the data on the server end?

Comment: I receive data on client side, today I convert data in server side. I looking for solution with javascript(maybe lib- jquery or yui have good solution for that)

Comment: Javascript is traditionally very poor when it comes to character set conversion. What kind of a request are you encoding? Is maybe base64 an option?

Answer (score 0):

I've made a [script for escaping Windows-1250](http://enux.pl/smp/js/QueryEncoding/localencoding.js) characters. You can create a translation table by yourself or generate from Wikipedia with a [translation table generation script](http://enux.pl/smp/js/QueryEncoding/) I used. The script should work at least on IE 7, FF 3.6 and Opera 11 (haven't tested on other browsers).

Example code for jQuery:

```
var sBaseUrl = 'ajax.script.php';
var oData = {
    some_param : 'Zażółć gęślą jaźń',
    other_param : '1',
};

// build url
var url = localBuildURL(sBaseUrl, oData);

// get
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'text',   // JSON doesn't always parse...
    success: function(txt, status, xhr)
    {
        // do something with txt
        // or parse with: data = $.parseJSON(txt);
    }
});
```

**Edit:** Actually... No translation table is needed for ISO-8591-1. All characters in it are one byte only. The `escape` function should be sufficient.

Answer (score -2):

You should be fine.  ISO-8859-1 I believe is completely encapsulated in UTF-8 with no issues.

Comment: Not true at all. All characters in ISO are indeed represented in UTF-8, but *only* the ASCII parts are byte identical between the two. All special characters have different mappings

Comment: yes pekka right, example : 'isn't' => "'" special char encoded differently

Comment: Pekka is wrong. All characters in the set are one byte only and they are correctly converted with the `escape` function.