# jquery Ajax response char problem

Tags: jquery, character-encoding

Through jquery ajax function, i am retreving data from server. everything seems fine but some german character displaying as '?' , Can anyone suggest me how to resolve this problem.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=iso-8859-1",
    url: url,
    async: true,
    timeout: timeOut,
    success: function (data, status)
    {
    if (status == "success")
    {
    displayHotelDetails(data);
    }
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The `contentType` parameter say how the `data` parameter (which you not use) will be encoded when the data are sent to the server. Moreover in the part of the jQuery.ajax documentation which describes `contentType` parameter you will find:

> Data will always be transmitted to the
>   server using UTF-8 charset; you must
>   decode this appropriately on the
>   server side.

So you should probably examine `Content-Type` HTTP header of the server response. You can use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).

You can explicitly set the in the HTTP header something like

```
response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=ISO-8859-1");
```

or

```
response.setContentType("application/x-json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
```

The call should be done on the server and so depend of the technology which you use.

Answer (score 0):

This will help

[Jquery: ajax post and encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965150/jquery-ajax-post-and-encoding)