# Error in encoding when using ajaxSubmit

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, encoding, character-encoding, ajax-forms

Hi I have a html page defined with:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

In a text field I type any latin alphabet character and in submit I receive the correct information in server.

Example: in field I type `"Descrição."` in server with: `Request["fieldname"]` I receive the same.

but now I need to change my submit to use ajaxSubmit, something like that:

```
$("#myform").ajaxSubmit({
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        // do something here.
    }
});
```

Now in server when I type `Request["fieldname"]`:

I receive `DescriÃ§Ã£o.`.

Clearly I've a problem with encoding here, but how fix it, any one can help me?

**Things that I already tried:**
- set accept-charset in form (I try `UTF-8` and `ISO-8859-1`)
- change the meta to: `<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">`
- set parameter `contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=iso-8859-1"` in ajaxSubmit call, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1229012/1233788)

But nothing worked so far. Any idea is welcome.