# accent ajax encoding issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, encoding, character-encoding, diacritics

Source file has:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=iso8859-1');
```

Source ajax (jQuery) script is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
});

$("#searchfield").keyup(function(){
    $("#insert_search")
        .load('ajax/searchobjects.php', {search_word:   $("#searchfield").val()}, function(){
        });
    });
});
```

Destination file:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=iso8859-1');

echo $_POST['search_word'];
```

Data sent:

```
é
```

Result is:

```
Ã©
```

All files:

```
Western (ISO Latin 1) (using TextWrangler)
```

Funny thing: I can insert records into MySQL just fine with accents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are displaying UTF-8 encoding of é (0xc3, 0xa9) as Latin-1. So the search_word was encoded as UTF-8 when it posted to PHP.

Try this,

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        scriptCharset: "iso-8859-1",
        cache: false
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because the default return type of an AJAX call is UTF-8. Try

```
utf8_encode($output);
```

in your ajax snippet. Alternatively, you can change the encoding of the AJAX request as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553463/jquery-ajax-character-encoding-problem).