# JQuery .html method character encoding

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, encoding

I have a similar problem to this: [jQuery AJAX Character Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553463/jquery-ajax-character-encoding-problem) but any solution mentioned there works for me.

I've made three easy files to show the problem:

**PHP File:**

```
//prueba.php
echo "nº one two € áéíóú";
```

**JavaScript File (I use JQuery)**

```
//Javascript file
    function prueba() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=ISO-8859-1",
            url: "prueba.php",
        }).done(function( data ) {
            $("#prueba").text(data); 
            //$("#prueba").html(data); //It does the same encoding error 
        });
    }
```

** HTML File:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>E-COMMERCE</title>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" http-equiv=Content-Type>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

        <script src="javascript/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="javascript/javascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <a href="javascript:prueba()">Prueba</a>
        <div id="prueba"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

And when you click the link Prueba it shows:

```
Prueba
n� uno dos � �����
```

The current website works perfectly but it does not use ajax and it is in the same server where i am doing this, so How can I tell to jquery to return ISO-8859-1 instead of whatever it is returning? I know that the ideal is to use always utf-8 but changing to utf-8 it will give us some problems we cant afford right now.

Comment: It shows:  "n? one two ? ????" but this example was really easy, I cannot do in the real one because it is returning a big string of html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make the browser use the correct encoding, you have to add an HTTP header to the php page :

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1");
```

or you could put the encoding in a meta tag of the html:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

Comment: I solved the main problem in the original by putting both of them, the header in the php file that gives me the full html code, and in the html where I update the selector. Thank you very much! I was really stocked with... this :)

Answer (score 0):

In your php file you'll need to [UTF-8 encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) the output:

```
echo utf8_encode("nº one two € áéíóú");
```

And then in your html file you will need to set the charset:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    ...
```

And for good practice specify a document type as well:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    ...
```

`<!DOCTYPE html>` is a legit [HTML5 doctype](http://ejohn.org/blog/html5-doctype/).

---

And as [Pranav Kapoor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13287153/887539) pointed out maybe you will need to specify the PHP-file charset aswell:

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
```

---

I can see you have specified your charset to: `ISO-8859-1`. I always work with `UTF-8` You can read more about it here: [What is the difference between UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048745/difference-between-utf-8-and-iso-8859-1)

But remove the `contentType` from your ajax call