# Encoding sending json to server using jquery

Tags: jquery, json, post, encoding, angularjs

I'm trying to send json data to a server using jQuery but every latin character is wrong at the server. I've already put everything to utf-8 charset. The characters get changed on the moment of the request. If I send something like `ç` it arrives as `√ß`. Here is my method:

```
01. function(atendimento, success) {
02.     var json = JSON.stringify({atendimento: atendimento});
03.     console.log('json: ', json);
04.     $.ajax({
05.         url: '/atendimentos/',
06.         data: json,
07.         contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
08.         dataType: "json",
09.         type: 'POST',
10.         success: function() {
11.             self.atendimentos.unshift(atendimento);
12.             success();                  
13.         }
14.      });
15.    };
```

line `02` prints:

```
json:  {"atendimento":{"chegada":"11/05/2013 15:49:00","paciente":"ç","procedimento":"ç","observacoes":"ç","agendado":false}}
```

However, this is what is sent to the server:

```
{"atendimento":{"chegada":"11/05/2013 15:49:00","paciente":"Ã§","procedimento":"Ã§","observacoes":"Ã§","agendado":false}}
```

And this is what is received:

```
{"atendimento":{"chegada":"11/05/2013 15:49:00","paciente":"√ß","procedimento":"√ß","observacoes":"√ß","agendado":false}}
```

I'm using angularJs and jQuery on the client and VRaptor on the server.

Comment: Did you save your files as UTF8 ?

Comment: Try encoding your string before sending it

[http://stackoverflow.com/a/2130775/336542][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2130775/336542

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the issue was with VRaptor framework that wasn't honoring the Accept-Charset Header. I've already submited a patch and everything should be fine. The parameter was submited encoded as ISO-8859-1 and wasn't decoded as UTF-8 as expected.