# JSP: Encoding of input parameter in form: Difference between IE and Firefox

Tags: forms, internet-explorer, jsp, firefox, utf-8

i have a JSP with

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

in the head section, with following code i try to set the content to UTF-8:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html;charset=utf-8" %>

response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Within a form is an input field:

```
<input type="text" value="LastName*" class="input required" name="lastName" id="lastName" />
```

I have now problems with german special characters.

When i use `request.getParameter("lastName")`, this works fine in FireFox, but not in IE.

`String encodedLastName = new String(request.getParameter("lastName").getBytes("iso-8859-1"), "UTF-8");`

works on IE, but not in Firefox.

I tried to change everything to `iso-8859-1`, added `accept-charset="UTF-8"` to the form, ...

Now it is more guessing than working.

Can this only configured within the server (Tomcat) but why there is a difference between the behaviour of the browsers?

Thank, Markus

Comment: What is actually happening in IE? You're getting the right character just in iso-8859-1, or do you get a question mark?

Comment: In Firefox the wrong character is shown as a white ? on a black diamond, in IE the wrong character is shown as two chars(!), a capital A with an ~ on top (in ISO 8859-1 table it is C3) and a special char, for instance ü (&uuml;) is 1/4 (in ISO 8859-1 table it is BC). The behaviour is the same if i switch in the browsers to another encoding (8859-1).

Comment: Basically you just need your JSP and the HTML meta tag to have the encoding match. Do you have <%@page contentType="text/html;charset=utf-8" %> on the very first line of the JSP?

Comment: Yes, as stated above, i have the <%@page line at the beginning, the <meta http-equiv line in the head, i set the character encoding in response AND request. That's why i am clueless, as it should work...

Comment: Ok, i have to change my problem to some jquery issue: When i disable javascript and i use <%@page ... %> and 
String encodedLastName = new String(request.getParameter("lastName").getBytes("iso-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
this works fine in IE and firefox. But when javascript is enabled, the jsp is called with AJAX like that
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: jqm('.validForm').attr('action'),
  data: jqm(".validForm").serialize(),
  success: function(data){
  $('.popupWrapper').hide().html(data).fadeIn(1500);
  }       
});

I think the problem lies in a different behaviour in the .serialize() function.

Comment: Try including content-type in your $.ajax(). See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553463/jquery-ajax-character-encoding-problem

Comment: contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8', should be default, accoring to api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax. But after set the contentType by hand, the IE and the FF behaviour is now the same. Problem solved; thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two problems which interfere with each other:

1) When using a normal post, i have to encode correct via

```
<%@page contentType="text/html;charset=utf-8" %>
```

and decode correct via

```
String encodedLastName = new String(request.getParameter("lastName").getBytes("iso-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
```

2) When using jquery, adding

```
contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
```

in the $.ajax call.