# incorrect encoding on dynamically added script tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On my page, I dynamically write an ajax response to my `DOM` by using `document.write(response)`.
everything loads fine, except for the hebrew part of a js script (that is linked to the loaded page with a  tag).

when loaded directly to a static page, everything works fine, but when being added by `document.write(response)`, it parses:

```
$.ajax({
url: "ajax/getContent.php",
type: "POST",
data: {category: "כללי"}
}).done(function(){...});
```

wrong, and כללי is sent url-encoded, but after being decoded as `Western(ISO-8859-1)`.

The weired thing is, it doesnt happen when the `<script>` tag is added directly.

Any thoughts?

thanks :)

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/553463/2752041), might be helpful.

Comment: Don't use URL-encoding, use JSON encoding.