# How to fix jquery ajax response with � (quotation mark block)

Tags: javascript, ajax, encoding, utf-8, utf

When I try to get html back from a ajax request I get multiple �. Why is this and how to correct it?

```
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: 'POST',
        url: Generic.ajaxSluice,
        dataType: "html",
        data:
        {
            param: paramArr
        },
        success:function(response)
        {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
```

This code gives me this response in the console:

[["������������������������...����������������������0", "../upload/images/Untitled-2.png"], ["1", "../upload/images/j.png"], ["2", "../upload/images/peppe.png"], ["�����������������������������������������"]]

Comment: You appear to be having encoding problems. You can try using `UTF-8` on both your page and the AJAX source response.

Comment: yeah i thought it could be an encoding problem. I could have mentioned that i actually have tried to convert to UTF-16 and back to UTF-8 to make sure that it was UTF-8. But that did'nt help realy. Can it be anything else?

Comment: To UTF-16 **from what**? Can you post your server-side code?

Comment: This is not yet solved :s Thanks for your tries though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX requires UTF-8. It's not even optional. From the [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) manual page:

> The W3C XMLHttpRequest specification dictates that the charset is
>   always UTF-8; specifying another charset will not force the browser to
>   change the encoding

Thus your server side code needs to read and write UTF-8. Period.

---

One way to verify if your server generates UTF-8 is to type a known char (I often use the `€` symbol) and see if you get the expected bytes (`E2 82 AC`). To get an hex dump:

- From server (PHP) you can use [bin2hex()](http://php.net/bin2hex) → `e282ac`
- From client (JavaScript) you can use [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) → `%E2%82%AC`

If you happen to see a lot of zeroes you're somehow getting [null characters](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0000/index.htm). That's a non-printable control code that should only appear on binary files (never on text). That reveals a different issue.

Comment: contentType (default: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8')

UTF-8 is default and i have'nt specified it in my request. Is there something wrong with the php and if so, how do i change it in php?

Comment: You can use any encoding with this technique: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553463/jquery-ajax-character-encoding#answer-553572

Comment: @KristofferFrisellJarnevid what matters here is the encoding that your **server** is actually using.

Comment: @KristofferFrisellJarnevid Declaring your encoding is one thing. Actually using it is a different one. PHP has `bin2hex()`. Just type a known char (e.g. `€`) and see if you get the expected bytes (`e282ac`).

Comment: @blex According to the jQuery docs, that will only work in some browsers in the best case.

Comment: It returns e282ac.

This is what i get:
0%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00e282ac%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00
....
%00 was after i used:

var test = escape(response);

Comment: Its strange. Everything is in UTF-8 and these are still there :/ What does null bytes mean?

Comment: Okey. Yeah. I opend my docs in another app and there i found them hiding at the bottom of all docs.

Comment: Okey. Thank you, specially Alvaro! This was solved by cleaning my php-files from ivisible bad Null characters that any of my applications have added.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out and thank you for reporting back. I've added the relevant information to the answer so it's more clear and useful for future readers.