# java how to escape accented character in string

Tags: java, jquery

For example

```
 {"orderNumber":"S301020000","customerFirstName":"ke ČECHA ","customerLastName":"张科","orderStatus":"PENDING_FULFILLMENT_REQUEST","orderSubmittedDate":"May 13, 2015 1:41:28 PM"}
```

how to get the accented character like "Č" in above json string and escape it in java

Just give some context of this question, please check this question from me 
[Ajax unescape response text from java servlet not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30249319/ajax-unescape-response-text-from-java-servlet-not-working-properly)

Sorry for my English :)

Comment: what do u mean by previous string?

Comment: Sorry for my English, I mean the json string

Comment: and what do you mean by escaping the "张科"?

Comment: Why is this question tagged for `jquery`? Or do you mean `javascript` instead of `java`?

Comment: turn it into \u5F20\u79D1\, my question is how to check whether there is a accented character in string

Comment: @JohnS because this string is in response from java servlet to ajax, I need to escape those accented character and then unescape them in jquery

Comment: you mean special characters?

Comment: I didn't know that Chinese characters could be accented...

Comment: have you tried using simple regex to find only the valid strings?

Comment: @AkashRajbanshi I mean latin character and language character, because those character in json response to ajax is causing parse error, even though I explicitly set chartset=utf-8 from both request and response

Comment: can you please give an example, not a good java programmer, sorry :)

Comment: oh you mean you don't have problem in java but while parsing it through client(jquery)?

Comment: exactly, when write latin character in response from java everything is working fine, just when parsing json from jquery, those accented character garbled

Comment: Check out this link. It might be helpful. http://www.javascripter.net/faq/escape.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should escape all characters that are greater than `0x7F`. You can loop through the String's characters using the `.charAt(index)` method. For each character `ch` that needs escaping, replace it with:

```
String hexDigits = Integer.toHexString(ch).toUpperCase();
String escapedCh = "\\u" + "0000".substring(hexDigits.length) + hexDigits;
```

I don't think you will need to unescape them in JavaScript because JavaScript supports escaped characters in string literals, so you should be able to work with the string the way it is returned by the server. I'm guessing you will be using JSON.parse() to convert the returned JSON string into a JavaScript object, [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/qud3yhgw/).

---

Here's a complete function:

```
public static escapeJavaScript(String source)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < source.length(); i++)
    {
        char ch = source.charAt(i);

        if (ch > 0x7F)
        {
            String hexDigits = Integer.toHexString(ch).toUpperCase();
            String escapedCh = "\\u" + "0000".substring(hexDigits.length) + hexDigits;
            result.append(escapedCh);
        }
        else
        {
            result.append(ch);
        }
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: can you please explain "\\u" + zeroPad(Integer.toHexString(ch).toUpperCase(), 4)

Comment: @kezhang -  That code will create a String like `\u5F20`. There should always be four digits, so the digits must be zero-padded on the left.

Comment: ok Thanks, why do you think I don't need to unescape the unicode, I need to get the unescaped value like Č in javascript

Comment: @kezhang - JavaScript supports escaped characters in string literals, so you should be able to work with the string the way it is returned by the server. I'm guessing you will be using `JSON.parse()` to convert the returned JSON string into a JavaScript object, [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/qud3yhgw/).

Comment: appreciate you help, I will try this overnight. I think I also need to figure out how the escape work, seems like Chinese does't treat as accented character, but why?

Comment: Sorry, I edit your answer, I put your explanation for jquery deal with Unicode in your answer, hope your don't mind, I should ask you first

Comment: @kezhang - You don't have high enough reputation to make an edit without out it being approved, but I think your edit was a good idea so I approved it.

Comment: Just a comment to add that you can html-escape your strings with the same method,with a line like `String escapedCh = "&#x" + "0000".substring(hexDigits.length()) + hexDigits + ";";`