# JSON incorrect encoding of characters in IE 11?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, internet-explorer

I am using json to send data from a website to the database. However, even that it works on all browsers (including IE 11), in IE 11 I don't get characters other than "english".

This is an example

```
$.getJSON('handler.php?type=contact&page='+page);
```

How can I fix this thing?

[image]

Comment: uhm... what? you're not sending json to the database.. additionally, you should be properly encoding that url value `page`

Comment: @KevinB how to properly encode the value ?

Comment: [jQuery AJAX Character Encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553463/jquery-ajax-character-encoding) may be of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you are not encoding the url parameter so that is an issue.

```
 $.getJSON('handler.php?type=contact&page='+encodeURIComponent(page));
```