# ajax - incomplete persian characters when getting data

Tags: ajax, unicode, character, persian

When the page loads itself characters are shwing correctly, but when I get the data using ajax the characters showing incomplete. for example فوتبال is correct but it shows فوتبالـ, or عکس is correct however it shows عکسـ.

I forgot to say this, when I alert the fetched data it shows correct but it shows partially like examples above when showing in page.

Thanks

Comment: There are quite a lot of suggestions about character encoding problems in ajax here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553463/jquery-ajax-character-encoding)

Comment: thank you very much for the good link but no result :(

Comment: can you put your sample code here? the html or js scripts?

Comment: That charachter seems to be `arabic tatweel`. http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/640/index.htm

Comment: I got the answer! As I said the string received was correct but not shown correct in span tag. So I changed the css and set display: inline-block. it worked!