# When using Wikipedia's opensearch api, the hashtag symbol will not populate the datalist. Why?

Tags: javascript, json, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api, opensearch

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: {
        'action': "opensearch",
        'format': "json",
        'search': search
    },
    success: function (data) {
        var suggestions = '';
        data[1].forEach(d => {
            suggestions += `<option value="${d}">`;
        });
        console.log(data);
        $('#searchList').html(suggestions);
        console.log(suggestions);
    }
});
```

[Difference between hashtag symbol from wikipedia search api and local server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kriny.png)

In other words the datalist populates just fine normally with other characters including @ or $, but when using # it will not drop down and show the suggestions even though the datalist is populated with the correct items when inspecting the element.

edit: by localhost I meant I changed the endpoint to my server so I could see what would happen if I sent back the option list with a hashtag. It worked fine and I noticed the different font between the hashtags sent by my server vs wiki's opensearch.

edit: The search variable comes from the input box like this-

```
<form class="pSearch form-inline" method="post" action="">
              <input class="pSearch" type="text" id="searchTerm" name="searchTerms" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" 
             list="searchList" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="true">
      <datalist id="searchList"></datalist>
```

I listen for input with the keyup function-

```
$('#searchTerm').keyup(function (e) {

    var search = $(this).val();
```

Then I send the variable search to the opensearch api-

```
    $.ajax({...})
}
```

Hardcoding the hashtag instead of using a variable works fine- "#". I tried JSON.stringify(search), but it made no difference.

Comment: Please post the result as text, not a painting.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "localhost"? What are you doing on your local host, what you doing with wikipedia?

Comment: edited my question to answer better explain what I meant Bergi. I used an image because I wondered if the difference between the two "#" characters had anything to do with it.

Comment: Please post the two server responses verbatim - they appear to be different. Then after establishing that, you probably will need to fix your local server to send the correct data.

Comment: There are multiple different characters: #♯⋕＃﹟ (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sign)). Maybe you used the wrong one in the response sent by your server. If you had posted text, I could confirm it.

Comment: First result from wikipedia is ＃2 ¡Una mas! , first result from my server is  #279886. They do look different. The datalist populates just fine when "#" is returned from my server. Wikipedia's "＃" will not populate the datalist. What is the difference between the two? Searching 'difference between ＃and #' did not yield relevant results.

Comment: When I put the two into the website https://unicodelookup.com/ I got number sign for the working hashtag, and utf-8 code  EF BC 83 for wikipedia's.

Comment: That's a "*FULLWIDTH NUMBER SIGN*", not the normal number sign. No idea how you made your server generate that. Fix it. Or show us the serverside code if you need help with it.

Comment: Bergi, That is coming from the wiki open search api, not my server.

Comment: I thought you said the wikipedia api is working, and your local server is not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that [Wikipedia article titles cannot contain a `#` character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Naming_conventions_(technical_restrictions)#Forbidden_characters). Apparently some people got creative and instead used the [*FULLWIDTH NUMBER SIGN* `＃`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sign#Unicode) instead to circumvent this limitation.

Correspondingly, the [normal search](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Search) would find [only a single accurate result for `#`](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=%23&title=Special%3ASearch&fulltext=Search&ns0=1), but the [Opensearch API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Opensearch) that you are using appears to do some unicode-aware fuzzy matching and returns pages beginning with `＃`. The `<datalist>` won't consider those however.

Comment: Okay, thank you! Now I won't waste anymore time on it. If I wouldn't have learned Wikipedia titles disallow #, I would have wasted so much more time than I already have. I really appreciate it! If anyone runs into similar issues, check out this question- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553463/jquery-ajax-character-encoding